# Meteor Atmosphere/Core Package Dependency Resolution Override (jquery, iron-router, blaze)

Tags: meteor, dependencies, package, version, conflict

I have a meteor application with the following packages:

```
$ meteor list

accounts-password      1.5.3  Password support for accounts
accounts-ui            1.3.1  Simple templates to add login widget...     
blaze-html-templates   1.1.2  Compile HTML templates into reactive...     
ecmascript             0.14.2  Compiler plugin that supports ES201...     
es5-shim               4.8.0  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAS...     
fourseven:scss         4.12.0  Style with attitude. Sass and SCSS ...     
iron:router            1.1.2  Routing specifically designed for Me...     
jquery                 1.11.11* Manipulate the DOM using CSS selec...     
meteor-base            1.4.0  Packages that every Meteor app needs        
mobile-experience      1.0.5  Packages for a great mobile user exp...     
mongo                  1.8.1  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimo...     
reactive-var           1.0.11  Reactive variable
shell-server           0.4.0  Server-side component of the `meteor...     
standard-minifier-css  1.6.0  Standard css minifier used with Mete...     
standard-minifier-js   2.6.0  Standard javascript minifiers used w...     
tracker                1.2.0  Dependency tracker to allow reactive...     
typescript             3.7.5  Compiler plugin that compiles TypeSc...     


* New versions of these packages are available! Run 'meteor update'       
  to try to update those packages to their latest versions. If your       
  packages cannot be updated further, try typing
  `meteor add <package>@<newVersion>` to see more information.
```

The atmosphere package `jquery` is available with version `3.0.0`. I had that until installing `iron-router`. I was able to successfully get `iron-router` installed by following this advice: https://forums.meteor.com/t/iron-router-jquery-dependency/51374 (specifically `meteor add iron:router --allow-incompatible-update`).

I'd like to use the newer `3.0.0`. I don't get the impression there is any true incompatibility within `iron-router`.

However, if I try to add it, I get:

```
$ meteor add jquery@3.0.0

-error: Conflict: Constraint jquery@1.0.0 is not satisfied by jquery       
3.0.0.
Constraints on package "jquery":
* jquery@3.0.0 <- top level
* jquery@1.11.9 || 3.0.0 <- blaze 2.3.4 <- accounts-base 1.5.0 <-
accounts-password 1.5.3
* jquery@1.11.9 || 3.0.0 <- blaze 2.3.4 <- blaze-html-templates
1.1.2
* jquery@1.0.0 <- iron:dynamic-template 1.0.12 <- iron:controller
1.0.12 <- iron:router 1.1.2
* jquery@1.0.0 <- iron:location 1.0.11 <- iron:router 1.1.2
```

Initially, I had a hard time seeing where it was getting `1.0.0` from for the iron:* dependencies since there was no explicit version listed:

- https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-dynamic-template/blob/devel/package.js#L14
- https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-location/blob/master/package.js#L13

Then I found this in [the documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/packagejs.html#PackageAPI-versionsFrom) for `api.versionsFrom(meteorRelease)`:

> Use versions of core packages from a release. Unless provided, all packages will default to the versions released along with meteorRelease. This will save you from having to figure out the exact versions of the core packages you want to use. For example, if the newest release of meteor is `METEOR@0.9.0 and it includes jquery@1.0.0, you can write api.versionsFrom('METEOR@0.9.0') in your package, and when you later write api.use('jquery'), it will be equivalent to api.use('jquery@1.0.0').

So that seems to be what is happening -- jquery@1.0.0 was [tied to `METEOR@0.9.2`](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-location/blob/master/package.js#L9).

---

So... aside from the option of checking out the `iron-*` packages into my local project as custom packages to override the `api.versionsFrom(meteorRelease)` in a custom fork to a modern release (or rather specify a specific jquery version since I believe it is no longer a core package)... is there any way forcefully update to `jquery@3.0.0` despite what it thinks is a conflict?

Unfortunately `--allow-incompatible-update` does not seem to work in this instance.

Comment: is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This a bit of opinionated but if you want to have a router without dependencies to outdated packages you should go with `ostrio:flow-router-extra` which allows you even to omit jQuery or install jQuery using the npm package.

Since Meteor 1.8.3 there is also no hard dependency between Blaze and jQuery, allowing to install the latest jQuery from npm registry, which is important from a security perspective.

Check out:
https://github.com/VeliovGroup/flow-router
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md

Answer (score 0):

Use @= to install a specific pkg version. You'll need to remove the npm jquery pkg if you downgrade.

```
meteor add jquery@=1.11.11
meteor npm remove jquery
meteor add iron:router
```